# Is there an "Edit Box" (highlight active/selected work area) equivalent for NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, editbox

When I was using eclipse, there was useful [Edit Box plugin](http://editbox.sourceforge.net/) to highlight portions of my code and that was very comfortable for me because sometimes I confuse lines when i'm tired.

Now I have to use NetBeans and I haven't been able to find something similar. Any way I can get similar functionality?

Comment: Thank you "user2864740" for correcting in proper English , it's not my native language , sorry.I did not know it was possible to edit the questions of someone else though.

Comment: I have made a quick search for it but cant find something similar fo NB

Comment: Thanks anyway, maybe i'll find someday

Comment: or you can create one for us ;)